# Rendering arrays with elements of different types without using default partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, partials

I get an array of search results from tire, containing objects of various activemodel types, and I need to render each to a string. Currently, I am doing this with a loop over these results calling render_to_string(result) on each. This uses the default partial for that activemodel object.

However, this requires that I set the default partial for every class I want to be searchable to be the representation for search. This means that everywhere else in the code I need to explicitly render a collection (all of the same type) I need to explicitly specify to render with my general-use partial, when really that general use partial should be the default. It also raises the question of what I would do if I needed to render a different collection of various types, as it would use the same partials as the search.

What I would really like would be to be able to pass a prefix to render_to_string that would tell it to look for the default partial, but inside this directory - which would mean I can keep my search partials separate while still being able easily render the objects.

Is there a way of doing that or some other better solution?

Comment: Have you tried things like `render_to_string([:search, result])`?

Comment: I like the idea, but I get `':search' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call:

```
 render_to_string :partial => 'searches/result', :collection => @results
```

And then within that one partial determine how the individual results should be displayed by doing:

```
case result.class.name
when 'Foo'
...
end
```

This gives me a single location for the format and display of results.

Comment: I'll give this a try, I would _prefer_ to do a prefix sort of thing and have separate partials but this is certainly far better than my current solution :)

Comment: Sub the stuff within the 'when' clause into seperate partials perhaps?

Comment: I guess I could build the partial name from the class name and render it using that

Comment: I wrote a partial with: `= render :partial => "search_#{search_result.class.name.downcase}", :object => search_result` and it worked great. Thanks :)